# AttributeError when creating tkinter.PhotoImage object with PIL.ImageTk

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library, photoimage

I am trying to place an image resized with PIL in a tkinter.PhotoImage object.

```
import tkinter as tk # I use Python3
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

master = tk.Tk()
img =Image.open(file_name)
image_resized=img.resize((200,200))
photoimg=ImageTk.PhotoImage(image_resized)
```

However, when I later try to call

```
photoimg.put( "#000000", (0,0) )
```

I get an

```
AttributError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute 'put'
```

While this:

```
photoimg=tk.PhotoImage(file=file_name)
photoimg.put( "#000000", (0,0))
```

doesn't raise an error.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you look at their implementations? They are not the same `PhotoImage` classes. They don't have the same implementation. You have to determine which one you want to use, and achieve your goal based on how that class is implemented.

Comment: Oh, thank you, this explains it. Is there a way to convert the `ImageTk.Photoimage` object to a `tkinter.Photoimage` object, or do i have to save the PIL image first and then load it into a tkinter.PhotoImage through it's filename?

Comment: I've never used either of those modules. I simply looked at the code of each and saw they were different. You would have to look in to the documentation to see what your options are. Look at the answer that was just posted. There is info provided.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ImageTk.PhotoImage` as in `PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage` is not the same class as `tk.PhotoImage` (`tkinter.PhotoImage`)  they just have the same name

here is ImageTk.PhotoImage docs:
http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/ImageTk.html#PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage
as you can see there is no put method in it.

but `ImageTk.PhotoImage` do have it:
http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/stdlib/Tkinter.PhotoImage-class.html

---

edit:

first link is now broken, this is the new link:

https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageTk.html?highlight=ImageTK#PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage

Comment: The first link is broken :(

Comment: added a new link :)

Answer (score 1):

My solution was something like this:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk()

file = 'image.png'

zoom = 1.9

# open image
image = Image.open(file)
image_size = tuple([int(zoom * x)  for x in image.size])
x,y = tuple([int(x/2)  for x in image_size])

# canvas for image
canvas = Canvas(root, width=image_size[0], height=image_size[1], relief=RAISED, cursor="crosshair")
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0)

ImageTk_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image.resize(image_size))
image_on_canvas = canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor = NW, image = ImageTk_image)

canvas.create_line(x-3, y, x+4, y, fill="#ff0000")
canvas.create_line(x, y-3, x, y+4, fill="#ff0000")
canvas.create_line(x, y, x+1, y, fill="#0000ff")

root.mainloop()
```